# Group values based on calculation dependent on another column

Tags: sql

I have a dataset that I want to sum the values for by category (item), however before I sum them together I need to convert the currency of some values dependent on the currency in another column.

Sample dataset:

```
Item    Currency    Value
1   USD 10
1   PHP 100
2   USD 50
2   PHP 1000
3   PHP 500
```

```
select ITEM, 
(case when CURRENCY='usd' then sum(VALUE*2) else sum(VALUE) end ) VALUE
from TABLE1 
inner join TABLE2 on TABLE1.ID=TABLE2.ID
inner join TABLE3 on TABLE3.X=TABLE1.X
inner join TABLE4 on TABLE1.Y=TABLE4.Y
where A=1 and B=2 and C=5 
group by ITEM, CURRENCY
ORDER BY ITEM asc
```

Desired outcome (using x2 as a factor to go from USD to PHP):

```
Item    Value
1   120
2   1100
3   500
```

However, I am getting the following, which has correctly converted the currency, but is not grouping by item (ie. i'm getting duplicated rows for item rather than 1 row with the summed value):

```
Item    Value
1   20
1   100
2   100
2   1000
3   500
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `case` should be the argument to the `SUM()`:

```
select ITEM, 
       sum(case when CURRENCY='usd' then VALUE*2 else VALUE
           end ) as VALUE
from TABLE1 join
     TABLE2
     on TABLE1.ID = TABLE2.ID join
     TABLE3
     on TABLE3.X = TABLE1.X join
     TABLE4
     on TABLE1.Y = TABLE4.Y
where A = 1 and B = 2 and C = 5 
group by ITEM
ORDER BY ITEM asc;
```

Note:  The `GROUP BY` is only by `ITEM`, because that defines the rows you want in the result set.

Comment: Hi Gordon, note that `VALUE`, if actually the column name, might require escaping in several flavors of SQL, as it is a keyword.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen . . . `VALUES` is a keyword; `VALUE` usually is not.